# org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Tags: spring-integration

While trying to run the below mentioned spring integration flow, I am getting an error :-

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [consumeTradeJSONChannelAdapter.container-9][]: Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
**org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.buildCitiFIXChannel'**.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

Please assist

```
<int:channel id="consumeTradeJSONChannel" />
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="consumeTradeJSONChannelAdapter" destination="consumetradejsonmessagesqueue"
    connection-factory="consumerauthenticationconnectionfactory" channel="consumeTradeJSONChannel"
    acknowledge="transacted" auto-startup="true" 
    concurrent-consumers="100"  max-concurrent-consumers="100" />
<int:channel id="buildCitiFIXChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="citiFIXMessageLogger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:json-to-object-transformer id="jsontoTradeBOtransformer"
    input-channel="consumeTradeJSONChannel" output-channel="buildCitiFIXChannel" type="com.citigroup.valueobject.TradeDetailsVO" />
<int:transformer id="citiFIXMessageBuilder" ref="citiFIXMessageBuilder" method="buildCitiFIXmessage" 
    input-channel="buildCitiFIXChannel" output-channel="endOfFlowChannel" />
<bean id="citiFIXMessageBuilder" class="com.citigroup.customtransformer.FIXMessageBuilder" />   
<int:channel id="endOfFlowChannel" />   
<int:bridge id="endofflow"  input-channel="endOfFlowChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="citiFIXMessageLogger" logger-name="citiFIXMessageLogger" level="INFO" log-full-message="true" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

> Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel `'application.buildCitiFIXChannel'`

This typically happens when a consumer on the channel is not started. Since your `citiFIXMessageBuilder` doesn't have an `auto-startup="false"`, it only can be a reason that `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` is started too early.

Consider to add a `phase="2147483647"` to the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` to start it as late as possible. (I assume that you use very old Spring Integration version because such a problem has been fixed for a while.)